# jquery autocomplete using '@'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to achieve this kind of [output](http://jsfiddle.net/peterwateber/gucPn/12/) (fiddler demo) using jQuery UI Autocomplete though.

The only problem with my example is that there is an issue in the arrow key events not like the jquery Autocomplete.

Comment: Hiya sup! so you want same behavior i.e. if in case value of the hidden tag as = @[C#] and the textarea as @C# but for this jsfiddle? cheers!

Comment: no not for this jsfiddle I wanna use the jquery autocomplete plugin... this one has issues try using your arrow keys and until you reach the end of the drop down but make sure to populate the textarea first

Comment: Okies, tried the arrow key and seems to wait for +1 event; If you can elaborate a bit more about your input and output need with jsfiddle I might be able to help you man. :)

Comment: actually the output of the jsfiddle is what I need... but I want to implement it using jquery autocomplete. the plugin I used was different and has problem with the arrow keys and selection... so can you do that on jquery autocomplete having the same output with the jsfiddle?

Comment: ummm... so you mean: using this http://jsfiddle.net/67dxH/ and the you want **1)** select from the text area and **2)** present value in the output text box? sorry if I might be asking too many question I just want to make it sure that I understand your question correctly :)

Comment: yeah using that one. so my textarea output would be "@peterwateber hello" and the input tag output would be "@[peterwateber] hello"

Comment: Saweet, got it, gimme 5 mins, will talk to you soon, cheerios!

Comment: saaweet man got the answer the ecaxt behavior you want, setting it up as answer now, cheers!

Comment: does it update during backspace?

Comment: Yep! :) indeed; chiching :P!!

Comment: I'm testing it i'll give my feedback

Comment: Lol okies, should I send my bank details by then lolz! ha ha <joke> :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the widget mentioned in this question and have fixed the problem:

http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9391/

Answer (score 2):

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/cH4p4/ **&&** http://jsfiddle.net/LxpQQ/

Like you mentioned using autocomplete:

> "so my textarea output would be "@c#" and the input tag output would
>   be "@[c#]"

**HTML**

```
<textarea id='inputbox' placeholder='When @mentions is called its output is put on the input box as well as updated when textarea is blur and submitted'></textarea>
<br/>
<input id="tags" />
<span id="loading" class="hidden">Loading...</span>
​
```

**Jquery Code**

```
function split(val) {
    return val.split(/@\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}

function getTags(term, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/tags",
        data: {
            filter: term,
            pagesize: 5
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: callback,
        jsonp: "jsonp",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    });    
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#inputbox")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            if (request.term.indexOf("@") >= 0) {
                $("#loading").show();
                getTags(extractLast(request.term), function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.tags, function(el) {
                        return {
                            value: el.name,
                            count: el.count
                        }
                    }));
                    $("#loading").hide();                    
                });
            }
        },
        focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            $("#tags").val("@["+ui.item.value+"]");
            ui.item.value = "@" + ui.item.value;                
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join("");
            return false;
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>@[" + item.label + "]&nbsp;<span class='count'>(" + item.count + ")</span></a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});​
```

**CSS**

```
span.count { 
    font-style: italic; 
    color: #C0C0C0;
}
.hidden { display: none; }

textarea { width: 300px; height: 100px; resize: none; }
​
```

Comment: there's something wrong... you can't use it multiple ways and it only appends the "@[mention]" not the whole string...

Comment: Umm how do you mean? if you will use the jsfiddle above and tell the input and output I will make the changes? make it in **point number** please :)

Comment: example you type this in textarea="@android hello @c#" and in the input box value should be "@[android] hello @a[c]"... but the one you posted is different. the text area is "android hello @c#" and the input box "@[c#]" it doesn't update

Comment: Aha so you also want that: **if you type @ foobad zoo @C# in texture; The input box should be @ foobad zoo @ [C#]** yeah??

Comment: no whatever is the string and the selected text form the dropdown e.g: "peter @peterwateber" the input box should update "peter @[peterwateber]". if backspace event happens in the textarea like e.g. from "peter @peterwateber" to "peter @peterwate" the input value should be "peter @peterwate" as you can see here in this example http://jsfiddle.net/peterwateber/gucPn/15/

Comment: Okies gimme 5 mins I might be able to do this in autocomplete.

Comment: Ok man @PeterWateber got it and let me know I will update my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/LxpQQ/ ; this should do the trick for your need & rest you can play around more let me know how it goes and don't forget to accept the answer :) CHeers!

Comment: still the same as the problem... its not updating... but thanks though

Comment: Hmm do you wanna sent me chat request <in stackoverflow> I will help you out :)) if you can tell me more about the behavior; How do you mean "its not updating", let me know what do you reckon! :) I am up to help you for this one now!

Comment: @Tats_iinit I'm still new to stackoverflow and I don't know how ping works how to do that? I'm in this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4790/jquery

Comment: @PeterWateber saweet I am in the chat room and pinged you, talk to you there!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following jquery plugin we just open sourced in GitHub: https://github.com/tactivos/jquery-sew