# How to use data entered into JQuery Autocomplete form?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, autocomplete

So i'm trying to pull the info entered into this form and use it for other things.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
Enter a School:
<input id="schoolsearch" type="text" /> 
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="GO">
</form>
```

I know this may seem like a simple question- but i just can't figure it out. This form is acting with a .php file that helps power the autocomplete function.

Would i just use METHOD=post or what?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with it? Is it like a search form that searches as you type?

Comment: I just deleted my post above on accident, but look up $.ajax, $.get, and $.post in the jquery documentation.

Comment: Yeah basically. Like the user begins typing in a School name- and it searched through the database of school names and matches them as the user types. it creates a dropdown of options as the user types. After the user types the full school name/or selects a name from the dropbox and hit's "go". I want to be able to use whatever it was they entered in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the outline of how ajax works in javascript. For more info see here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/.

`run this on.keypress()`

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: url, //url of the php file that searches for schools with the given value
data: data, // the data you are sending so something like $('#school').val()
success: success, // prepare to catch what the php returns 
dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiya please see **demo** here: http://jsfiddle.net/vZtGs/ **or** please see one of my old replies using few more options in here: [jquery autocomplete using '@'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060931/jquery-autocomplete-using)

good read here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ (with other options and events supported)

**Code**

```
$( "#autocomplete, #schoolsearch" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( req, resp ) {
        $.post( "/echo/json/", {
            json: '["School1", "School2", "School3", "School4", "School5"]',
            delay: 1
        }, function(data) {
            resp( data );
        }, "JSON" );
    },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            //var terms = split(this.value);
            alert('Do whatever with this value man: ' + ui.item.value);
            return false;
        }
});
​
```