# Detect entered character with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keyboard, multilingual

I'd like to start an action (enabling autocomplete) when user types '@'. I have jQuery available.

Usually on a QWERTY keyboard, it is like this:

```
$('textarea').live('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 50) {
    console.log('@ has been entered.');
  }
});
```

However it does not work correctly on an AZERTY keyboard. The keyCode = 50 corresponds to the <kbd>é</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> key. To type '@' in AZERTY keyboard, it is <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>à</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> key.

Edit: Autocomplete starts when @ is entered, and only after that. Example, when someone enters "Hello @" then it starts, however when he types "Hello @nothing else" the complete won't do anything. Example: http://mrkipling.github.com/jQuery-at-username/ (it works only on QWERTY keyboard).

Comment: D'oh, I didn't notice what StackOverlow have exactly what I need with the username autocomplete feature in the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `keypress` instead of `keydown`. While `keydown` relates to every press of a key, `keypress` relates to the translated characters, so for example `a` can be different to `a` while the <kbd>shift</kbd> key is pressed, composed characters work, dead-keys work, and other differences in keyboard mappings are handled.

Comment: Exactly! The `keypress` event detects correctly the code of `@` (64). I think I'll have to separate the two event: one to detect the `@` character, another using `keydown` to detect the arrow keys for the "complete" part.

Comment: @jcisio That makes sense. However, I'm not sure about unified browser support of `keypress`.

Comment: @VisioN it's better than unified browser support for keydown and keyup!

Comment: @VisioN I'm not sure I correctly understand what you say. keypress event is supported in jQuery, and the event.which is also normalized across browser by jQuery.

Comment: @jcisio I mean if all browsers (and OS) will give you 64 on `keypress`. All mine do but still I'm not sure. Anyway, as Jon says it is better than `keydown` and `keyup`.

Comment: Because it depends upon some of the less well-standardised features in browser javascript implementations, jquery docs flag it as not being one they can give particularly good guarantees of it working well. That said though, the same is also true of keydown, and even more so!

Comment: @jcisio Here is some info about key events compatibility: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html.

Answer (score 2):

How about checking if `@` was entered as the last character in the field value?

```
$("body").on("keyup", "textarea", function(e) {
    if (this.value.indexOf("@") == this.value.length - 1) {
        console.log("Starting autocomplete");
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FKhPW/2/

Comment: Thanks, it basically does what I'd like to do. There are a few case, for example, when user finishes a message, then moves to the begin and adds '@username' it won't work. I'll try to adapt it.

Comment: @jcisio Yes, it possibly might need some correction. At least I do not see any other fast and working solutions.

Answer (score 2):

## Use `event.key` and modern JS, checking for `@` directly!

*No number codes* anymore. You can check key directly.

```
const input = document.getElementById("textarea");
input.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.key === "@") {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Answer (score 0):

The only other option that comes to mind would be a timer that checks the content of the text input.

```
var patt=new RegExp(/^@/);
var charCheck = setInterval(function(){
  if (patt.test($("#textInput").val())){
    // initiate autocomplete
  }
},100);
```

This code will inspect the contents of the `#textInput` element and see if it matches the regular expression of a `@` symbol at the beginning of the string.  If it does, the `test()` function will evaluate to true and you can initiate your autocomplete code.

Comment: It should check for @ anywhere in the textarea, and the autocomplete only starts when the cursor is right after the '@' character. I think it is still possible to verify all of these conditions, however is there any simpler solution?

Comment: @jci - You should  mention the specification about the cursor position in your main post.  Also if you want to search for that symbol anywhere in the string simply remove the `^` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go **working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/LxpQQ/

From my old reply here:

[jquery autocomplete using '@'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060931/jquery-autocomplete-using)

Hope it will fit you cause `:)`

**code**

```
source: function(request, response) {
            if (request.term.indexOf("@") >= 0) {
                $("#loading").show();
                getTags(extractLast(request.term), function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.tags, function(el) {
                        return {
                            value: el.name,
                            count: el.count
                        }
                    }));
                    $("#loading").hide();                    
                });
            }
        },
```

Comment: Thanks, while I'm avoiding jQuery UI (and its autocomplete library), this example has a few intelligent point, like it gets only the last term etc. I'm bookmarking for later usage.